# Can't enable Hyper-V - Error 0x80070057

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, hardware-virtualization

I'm currently trying to enable Hyper-V on my HP ProBook 450 G2 with Windows 10 Education but I get error code 0x80070057.

I already checked the following things:

- Virtualization is enabled in the bios.
- I have uninstalled VirtualBox.

Does someone know what the cause of this problem is and how I can fix it?

Comment: 0x80070057 = ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER. To see what is wrong, copy the folder C:\windows\logs\CBS to your desktop after a failed setup, zip the folder, upload the zip to Onedrive, create a share link and post the link here.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, you can find the content of the CBS folder [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B--vIjbbTdM7OVRlZ0xKY3ZIYUU&usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seams to be an issue with a `nl-nl` MUI file:

> 2015-11-15 12:52:18, Info                  CSI    00000061
>   Regenerating payload files from delta files on component:
>   [ml:280{140},l:206{103}]"amd64_microsoft-hyper-v-i..nents-rdv.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_nl-nl_beed44968ce52985"
>       2015-11-15 12:52:18, Error                 CSI    00000062@2015/11/15:11:52:18.160 (F)
>   base\wcp\componentstore\deltastore.cpp(2871): Error
>   STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER originated in function
>   ComponentStore::CRawStoreLayout::RecursivelyRegenerateComponentPayload
>   expression: false
>       [gle=0x80004005]

and the WinSxS compression. Try to run [DISM](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx) to repair WinSxS issues.

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

The `10.0.10240.16384` shows me that you still use the first Windows 10. Update to the November 2015 / Fall Update Version 1511 and try again if you can use Hyper-V.

Comment: Thank you very much, after running the `DISM` command and installing the November 2015 update of Windows 10 installing Hyper-V worked fine.